# How to ignore a property from serialization but keep in for deserialization using json.net in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

How to ignore a property from serialization but keep in for deserialization using json.net in c#.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contentType")]
    public object ContentType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public object Content { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Relationship RelationshipContent { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Domains DomainContent { get; set; }

}
```

in the above code i need to deserialize the "content" into the property "RelationshipContent" and "DomainContent" according to the  value to the PartType property value.

Can you help me how to do it in C# using Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have a method for the 'set' of `Content` and process the data into the right place.

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contentType")]
    public object ContentType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public object Content { get; set {
            //do something here with `value` e.g.
            RelationshipContent = value; //change as required
            DomainContent = value; //change as required
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Relationship RelationshipContent { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Domains DomainContent { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Glad to have helped.